# Why can't I ping or access web portal of a printer that has a public ip in an internal network?

Tags: ip, printer, dhcp, network-printer, private-network

I setup a new printer in the office. I printed a status page and it had the IP of 192.168.x.x. I couldn't ping it as it wasn't a part of our company and didn't have private IP.

If 192.168.x.x wasn't a valid IP then why did the printer receive that IP from DHCP?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You apparently set it up wireless (consider using Ethernet) and it got its IP from a different network nearby.

Comment: No, that new printer isn't a wireless printer and it is connected via ethernet cable. In an internal network, how did a new printer get a public IP address in the first place?

Comment: Better to give us the **actual** IP adresses, otherwise we can't tell what happened. Neither of those is a public IP.

Comment: Reset the printer to factory specs and try again. An Ethernet device does not wander off network. Do you have it on a router with some sort of isolation involved ? Isolation is normally for wireless. Contact manufacturer's support.

Comment: @tetsujin Yes, sorry, you are right 192.168 is a 3rd private IP address range. So our company network is 10.0.0.0, but the new printer got the ip of 192.168.x.x. I am trying to find how did the DHCP release an IP of a different range which is not even a part of our network.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, as an example.

If your network is on the `192.168.0.0/24` network and your printer is getting a different IP all together but is on the same network, then I'd say that this could be an issue with maybe having multiple DHCP servers on the network if the printer is getting an IP on a different subnet `192.168.100.0/24`, then this is where you would really want to know how your network is working, cause this would have to come from another DHCP server on the network if not set statically.

If you are getting a `169.254. 0.0-169.254.255.255`for Automatic Private IP Addressing then this would mean that your printer is not really connected to the network yet and there could be some issue on a [leyer 1 or 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/layers-of-osi-model/)

Comment: Our network is 10.0.0.0, but the new printer got the ip of 192.168.x.x. I can't understand why a DHCP server would give an IP of a different private address range.
Do I have to ask our sys admin if we have more than one DHCP servers?
OR does a new printer by default gets an IP of 192.168 private IP range?

Kindly assist.

Comment: I would ask them; in my experience, depending on the location, things like this can happen. Let's say if a location has multiple network devices at one location, this could happen, where maybe even one router is giving out a certain DHCP range, based on the VLAN that it's connected to.